# How to use \tikzexternalize and the overlay option at the same time?

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays, tikz-external, externalize

I am trying to create a cover page in LaTeX with Tikz (the example provided is very simple but the goal is to have a more detailed cover page). I am using PDFLaTeX.

I have to use the `overlay` option on the `tikzpicture` environment in order to be able to place the elements on all the page. But It does not seem to work. If I don't use *tikzexternalize*, then it works fine, but I cannot cache the cover page and it will have to be recompiled every time. If I don't use `overlay` the page is not rendered as it should.

Here is the source code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]

% Background color
\fill[black!2] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);

% Title
\node[align=center] at ($(current page.center)+(0,-5)$){
  {\fontsize{60}{72} \selectfont {{Title of the Report}}} \\[1cm]
  {\fontsize{16}{19.2} \selectfont \textcolor{orange}{ \bf Author Name}}\\[3pt]
  Company Name\\[3pt]
  Address
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here are the pdf outputs I get:

[image]
[image]
[image]

From left to right, the images correspond to the following setup:

- `overlay` enabled, `tikzexternalize` disabled **(wanted output, but not cahed)**
- `overlay` enabled, `tikzexternalize` enabled **(everything disappears...)**
- `overlay` disabled, `tikzexternalize` enabled **(cached, but not correct form)**

Any clue on how to fix this? I should mention that the *figures* directory already exists, and I use `-shell-escape` when compiling.

Comment: You could use tikz externalize to create a paper sized image (\paperwidth by \paperheight), then tikz overlay to draw it.  OTOH, `\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{...}` would also do.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I am sorry but I am quite new to all of this. Could you provide a sample code for your first solution? I cannot figure out how to achieve it.

Comment: Actually, no.  I have never gotten shell escapes to work.  I can show you how to do it with standalone (which is what externalize does anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this example, it's best not to use externalize. See the Comment at the end.

I suggest a two-step procedure:

**(1)** Generate the background image. Or put a nice image you already have (with same dimensions as the paper in order to fill the page entirely).

**(2)** Produce the title page using the already generated background,  adding the specific titles of this document.

The *overall effect is the same as externalizing*, as the background image will be generated only once, and it can be reused in other documents.

[image: a]

This is `TitleBackground.tex` It will produce a light blue rectangle with the size of the physical page. You can add logos and other text that will not be changed in the future. Run it first.

```
%%  TitleBackground

% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty} % Suppress headers and footers 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node [anchor=center, inner sep=0cm, rectangle, fill=blue!10!white, fill opacity=0.6, text opacity=1, minimum height=\paperheight, minimum width=\paperwidth, text width=\paperwidth] at (current page.center) {};
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is `main.tex` with a redefinition of `\titlepage` to incorporate the background and insert the title, author, etc in a centered darker blue rectangle.

```
%% File main.tex

% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    
%****************************************  added <<<<<<<<<< 
\renewcommand{\titlepage}[2]{%
    \thispagestyle{empty} % Suppress headers and footers on the title page
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node [inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center) {#1}; % insert the background image
        \node [anchor=center, inner sep=2.0cm, rectangle, fill=blue!30!white, fill opacity=0.6, text opacity=1, minimum height=0.3\paperheight, minimum width=\paperwidth, text width=0.8\paperwidth] at (current page.center) {#2}; % Highlight box with title and author
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    \newpage
    \setcounter{page}{1} %start on page 1
}
%**************************************** 

\begin{document}
    
\titlepage % output the title page
{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{TitleBackground.pdf}} %
{ % Title(s) and author(s)
    \centering\sffamily % 
    {\Huge\bfseries Title of the Report\par} % % Report title
    \vspace{20pt} % vertical space
    {\LARGE \textcolor{orange}{Author Name}\par} % % Author 
    \vspace{60pt} % vertical space
    {\huge\bfseries Company Name\par}  %  Company
        \vspace{20pt}
    {\large\bfseries Address\par} %  Company
}

\section{One}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

**Comment** on externalize. It is a very useful tool if you have a document with many tikz figures. Since it will generate each figure once, subsequent runs will be much faster. The figures will be inserted from the already generated `.pdf` at the correct insertion point.

This is the problem of the title page. The background figure is generated correctly but is inserted at the origin of the first line of the text area, rather than the top left corner of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the standalone to generate the image (named figure.pdf).

```
\documentclass[class=article]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Background color
\fill[black!20] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth, \paperheight);
% Title
\node[align=center] at (0.5\paperwidth,0.5\paperheight-5cm){
  {\fontsize{60}{72} \selectfont {{Title of the Report}}} \\[1cm]
  {\fontsize{16}{19.2} \selectfont \textcolor{orange}{ \bf Author Name}}\\[3pt]
  Company Name\\[3pt]
  Address
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

And this adds the image to the document using both TikZ and `\AddToHookNext`.  The only difference is that TikZ takes two runs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node at (current page.center){\includegraphics{figure.pdf}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage

\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put(0pt,-\paperheight){\includegraphics{figure.pdf}}}
\null\newpage
\end{document}
```